# SQL - Getting data to display from current date forward

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to display data from my Seminar I want the general users to only be able to see the Seminars from the current date forward and the admins to see the old ones as well which I can do that bit.

this is the query I have tried, the table is called Seminar and the column I'm using is time which is a DATE/TIME function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Seminar 
WHERE time >= CURDATE() 
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Right okay so I have a table called 'Seminar' and I want to produce a queried output of the seminars from todays date for example; but inside this table I have old seminars which are prior to todays date. When I run the above code it displays all the seminars and not what I want it to display. I played around with the relational operators too. @gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query seems fine. If you run a separate one for your admins which doesn't have the `WHERE` clause, you'll have your problem solved.